# How to declare a variable of rowtype in teradata stored procedures?

Tags: teradata

I want to store the output of a query in a variable and then I will use this result in further calculation in a trigger.  I am using teradata and I am new bee in teradata. Please help.

Comment: what you have tried so far. please share code/

Comment: please look into this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455866/select-into-variables-in-teradata-while-creating-trigger
I have tried this and seems inserting into multiple variables is not possible in teradata, so I want to store values first into a rowtype variable and then I will assign values to variables from the rowtype variable

Comment: if I have to suggest then there is no way in teradata to do this rowtype. However you have to create volatile tables or temp tables of same structure and do the job. Teradata architecture supports very good use of volatile tables please use. Dont waste your time on rowtype or select into clause because they dont exist for teradata.

Comment: but if I am using volatile table to store the output of query then how will I set the values in the inserting row? again I will have to set the values by selecting one by one into each column

Comment: Yes you are right. You have to search faster approach in that. Why to use a rowtype and volatile table? Insert into targettable select <do the calculation with column> from source table